# Plotting asymmetric error bars Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So I have three sets of data:

```
min_data = np.array([ 0.317, 0.312, 0.305, 0.296, 0.281, 0.264, 0.255, 
0.237, 0.222, 0.203, 0.186, 0.17, 0.155, 0.113, 0.08])

avg_data = np.array([ 0.3325, 0.3235, 0.3135, 0.30216667, 0.2905, 0.27433333, 
0.26116667, 0.24416667, 0.22833333, 0.20966667, 0.19366667, 0.177, 
0.16316667, 0.14016667, 0.097])

max_data = np.array([ 0.346, 0.331, 0.32, 0.31, 0.299, 0.282, 0.266, 0.25, 
0.234, 0.218, 0.204, 0.187, 0.175, 0.162, 0.115])
```

I need to plot this data with error bars.

I have attempted:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 15)
err = [min_data, max_data]
plt.errorbar(x, avg_data, 'bo', yerr=err)

TypeError: errorbar() got multiple values for argument 'yerr'
```

The final graph should look like this:

```
plt.plot(x[::-1], avg_data, 'ro')
plt.plot(x[::-1], min_data, 'bo')
plt.plot(x[::-1], max_data, 'bo')
```

[image]

Where the blue points represent where the error bars should be located.

All the documentation I have been able to find only allows asymmetric errors that is equal in + and - y directions.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is failing because it thinks that `'bo'` is the `yerr` argument since the third argument in `plt.errorbar` is `yerr`.  If you want to pass the format specifier, then you should use the `fmt` keyword.

```
plt.errorbar(x, avg_data, fmt='bo', yerr=err)
```

Comment: Ahh, didn't expect that.. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleHunter No problem.  P.S. I plotted your data, and you're going to need to subtract the average from the max and min to get the type of error bars that you're looking for.

Comment: Yep I saw that, easy to change :)